# Prevent sass colour names from expanding inside interpolation

Tags: sass, interpolation

I'm trying to automatically build some selectors to assist in tinting zurb foundation flyouts.

I'm pretty sure I had this working before. But before I get into specifics, here is the sass :

```
.flyout
    @each $color in (green, brown, blue, darkred, maroon, saddlebrown)
        &.#{$color}
            border: 1px solid tint($color, 10%)
            background: tint($color, 20%)
```

I'm pretty sure there will be some people offended by my approach here, regardless I'd like the result to look like :

```
.flyout.green{
    border: 1px solid the-ten-percent-tinted-green;
    background: the-twenty-percent-tinted-green;
}

... etc, etc
```

Instead I get :

```
>>> Change detected at 12:08:57 to: components/zurb/_flyout.sass
    error sass/app.sass (Line 132 of sass/components/zurb/_flyout.sass: Invalid CSS after "&.": expected class name, was "#8b4513")
```

Comment: nope not a duplicate.

Comment: How do you figure it's not a duplicate?  Your color keywords are being converted to their hexidecimal equivalent.  It doesn't matter where the color occurs (class name, property value, etc.), only what compression mode you're using.

Comment: Those other two are to do with using colour values, this is to do with using the colour names as they are. I don't want them to be converted into hex-values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you were getting that error; the provided `+coloured-flyout` in your example wasn't quite working because it expected two inputs.

Here's the .sass that does what you're asking for:

```
=coloured-flyout($color)
  border: solid tint($color, 10%) 1px
  background-color: tint($color, 20%)

.flyout
  @each $color in green, brown, blue, darkred, maroon, saddlebrown
    &.#{$color}
      +coloured-flyout($color: $color)
```

It compiles to:

```
.flyout.green {
  border: solid #198c19 1px;
  background-color: #339933;
}
.flyout.brown {
  border: solid #ae3f3f 1px;
  background-color: #b75454;
}
.flyout.blue {
  border: solid #1919ff 1px;
  background-color: #3333ff;
}
.flyout.darkred {
  border: solid #961919 1px;
  background-color: #a23333;
}
.flyout.maroon {
  border: solid #8c1919 1px;
  background-color: #993333;
}
.flyout.saddlebrown {
  border: solid #96572a 1px;
  background-color: #a26a42;
}
```

Live example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7833015

Comment: The problem wasn't with the usage of a mixin, the problem was with the  interpolation expanding a colour name into it's hex variable. Hence the title of the question.

Comment: @airtonix - Could you please clarify the problem that you're having?  Even without out the mixin, the .sass does compile to CSS with selectors like `flyout.green`

Comment: It does now, however when I made this post it would attempt to come out as `.flytout.#8b4513` which caused that error. I suspect it was something to do with compass. But like I said. it no longer happens.